# Is it possible to install the Memcached extension for PHP 7 alongside a PHP 5.6 install?

Tags: memcached, centos7, php-7

Is it possible to install the Memcached extension for PHP 7 on CentOS7 alongside a Memcached with PHP 5.6 install? The server is running DirectAdmin custombuild 2.0 which lets you run 2 PHP versions alongside each other.

And [this Memcached installation guide](https://github.com/kasparsd/php-7-debian) is for Debian, what would be different / would it work for CentOS7?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install PHP 7 extension "memcached" on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107027/how-to-install-php-7-extension-memcached-on-windows)